# Does printing cause SSRS to re-render, and if so is there any way around it?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report I'm building in SSRS.  I have text box that makes use of custom code at the bottom of the report (not in the footer).  This is the function in use:

```
=Code.WinnerTextBox(First(Fields!WinnerName.Value, "FightDetails" ),First(Fields!Blue_Corner.Value, "Judge1"),First(Fields!Red_Corner.Value,"Judge1"),First(Fields!FightDecisionCode.Value, "FightDetails" ),First(Fields!DecisionTypeName.Value, "FightDetails" ),First(Fields!FightDecisionRoundNo.Value, "FightDetails" ), First(Fields!FightDecisionTime.Value,"FightDetails" ),First(Fields!SubmissionTypeName.Value, "FightDetails" ))
```

Here is the custom code in use:

```
Public Class CalculateTotals
                Dim public redTotal AS Integer
                Dim public redRoundTotal AS Integer
                Dim public blueTotal AS Integer
                Dim public blueRoundTotal AS Integer

                Public Function AddRedTotal(ByVal RedCornerDeduction AS Integer, ByVal RedCornerPoints AS Integer) AS Integer
                                redRoundTotal = RedCornerPoints - RedCornerDeduction
                                redTotal = redTotal + redRoundTotal
                                return redRoundTotal
                End Function

                Public Function GetFinalRed()
                                return redTotal
                End Function

                Public Function AddBlueTotal(ByVal BlueCornerDeduction AS Integer, ByVal BlueCornerPoints AS Integer) AS Integer
                                blueRoundTotal = blueCornerPoints - blueCornerDeduction
                                blueTotal = blueTotal + blueRoundTotal
                                return blueRoundTotal
                End Function

                Public Function GetFinalBlue()
                                return blueTotal
                End Function

                Public Function GetLeaderName(ByVal RedName AS String, ByVal BlueName AS String) AS String
                                IF GetFinalBlue() > GetFinalRed() Then
                                                return BlueName
                                ElseIf GetFinalRed() > GetFinalBlue() Then
                                                return RedName
                                ElseIf GetFinalRed() = GetFinalBlue() Then
                                                return "Draw"
                                Else
                                                return "Something is very wrong with the data"
                                End If
                End Function
End Class

Dim Public Judge1 AS CalculateTotals = New CalculateTotals()
Dim Public Judge2 AS CalculateTotals = New CalculateTotals()
Dim Public Judge3 AS CalculateTotals = New CalculateTotals()
Dim Public red AS Integer
Dim Public blue AS Integer
Dim Public leader AS String

Public Function GetRed() AS Integer
                red = Judge1.GetFinalRed() + Judge2.GetFinalRed() + Judge3.GetFinalRed()
                return red
End Function

Public Function GetBlue() AS Integer
                blue = Judge1.GetFinalBlue()+Judge2.GetFinalBlue()+Judge3.GetFinalBlue()
                return blue
End Function

    Public Function WinnerTextBox(ByVal Winner As String, ByVal BlueCorner As String, ByVal RedCorner As String, ByVal DecisionCode As Integer, ByVal DecisionType As String, ByVal DecisionRound As Integer, ByVal FightDecisionTime As String, ByVal SubmissionType As String) As String
        Dim ReturnString As String
        If (GetBlue() = GetRed()) Or (DecisionCode = 10) Or (DecisionCode = 11) Or (DecisionCode = 12) Then
            ReturnString = "Draw: " & CStr(GetBlue()) & "-" & CStr(GetRed()) & " (" & DecisionType & ")"
        ElseIf (Winner Is Nothing) Then
            If (GetBlue() > GetRed()) Then
                ReturnString = "Leader: " & BlueCorner & CStr(GetBlue()) & "-" & CStr(GetRed())
            Else
                ReturnString = "Leader: " & RedCorner & CStr(GetRed()) & "-" & CStr(GetBlue())
            End If
        ElseIf (DecisionCode = 1) Then
            ReturnString = "Winner: " & Winner & " By " & DecisionType & " In Round " & CStr(DecisionRound) & " At " & FightDecisionTime
        ElseIf (DecisionCode = 9) Then
            ReturnString = "Winner: " & Winner & " By " & DecisionType & " " & SubmissionType & " In Round " & CStr(DecisionRound) & " At " & FightDecisionTime
        ElseIf Winner = BlueCorner Then
            ReturnString = "Winner (" & CStr(GetBlue()) & "-" & CStr(GetRed()) & "): " & Winner & " By " & DecisionType & " In Round " & CStr(DecisionRound) & " At " & FightDecisionTime
        ElseIf Winner = RedCorner Then
            ReturnString = "Winner (" & CStr(GetRed()) & "-" & CStr(GetBlue()) & "): " & Winner & " By " & DecisionType & " In Round " & CStr(DecisionRound) & " At " & FightDecisionTime
        End If
        Return ReturnString
```

Now when the report is run, it renders absolutely correct on the screen, however when it is exported to PDF or printed, the textbox renders the following text:

Draw: 0-0 (KNOCKOUT)

This leads me to believe that the process of printing my report is causing the custom code to somehow try to run again, and has no data and therefore returns this.  Is there a way to prevent that from occurring?  Is that what is happening?  And if so, can you help me understand why it is re-rendering when printing?  Also, any suggestions on how to make this print properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a similar issue (I think).  We were running much simpler code to get a running total.  Using print, print preview or export to PDF would act like it is running twice on the tablix.  The fix for us was to create another function to initialize.  I would try something like this;

```
Public function Initialize()
redTotal = 0
redRoundTotal =0
blueTotal =0
blueRoundTotal =0
end function
```

for our purpose we had to add another row to our tablix and put the text =code.initialize in a textbox in the new row.  I tried putting this all over the page, in the header and footer, everywhere, and the only place that it would work is if it was at the very end of the tablix where the running total was being used.

not sure where to put this if you are using this code in a textbox, maybe there is a way to add multiple code calls to the same textbox???